# How often will a horse egg contain a donkey?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently heard that you can spawn a donkey from a horse egg with a random probability so I am curious: how often does this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the Minecraft Wiki:](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_egg)

> Horse will spawn 90% of the time; donkey 10% of the time. A foal will be spawned 20% of the time.

The foal will mature into a horse 90% of the time and a donkey 10% of the time.

Comment: Those numbers don't add up.

Comment: @GnomeSlice A foal can presumably be either a donkey or a horse. In other words: 72% adult horse, 18% baby horse, 8% adult donkey, 2% baby donkey.

Comment: and 0% dinosaur :(

Comment: so the probability of it being a horse and the probability of it being a donkey are mutually exclusive, and the probability of it being an adult and the probability of it being a foal are mutually exclusive, however the whether it is a horse or donkey is independent of whether it is born an adult or foal. If H, D, A, and F represent horse, donkey, adult, and foal respectively, then P(H^A)=P(H)*P(A), P(H^F)=P(H)*P(F),P(D^A)=P(D)*P(A), P(D^F)=P(D)*P(F), P(H)+P(D)=1,P(A)+P(F)=1

Answer (score -2):

A horse spawn egg rarely contains a Donkey. There is a 5% chance the egg will spawn a Donkey, a 75% chance it will spawn a horse, and a 20% chance it will spawn a foal.

Upon maturing, the foal will grow up as either a donkey or a horse. If a foal turns into a donkey, well congrats.

Comment: Your answer seems to contradict the information provided in the wiki.  Where did you get your information?